# How to send an xml from a c# desktop application to a php server script and parse it?

Tags: c#, php, .net, xml, desktop-application

In my project I suppose to write a desktop app that sends an xml document as file or as string,
to a php script on server that need to parse it.
Right now, I have php script that parse the xml, and have the xml ready at the desktop app.
My questions are:
a. which way is better: to send the document as file, or as string? 
b. How to implement the request (file or string) by C#, and the acception of the document by php.

Notes:
a. I can use only C# at the desktop application.
b. I can use only php script on the server.
c. I use System.xml.linq to handle the xml document at the desktop app.

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This can be as simple or as complex as you like ;-)
Here's a very simple, basic example (without error handling et al):

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml.Linq;
using System.Net;

namespace LinqXMLTest
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Object[] res = { "Stackoverflow", true, 'x', 42};
            XElement xml = new XElement("Foo",
                from a in res select
                    new XElement("bar",
                        new XElement("type", a.GetType()),
                        new XElement("value", a.ToString())
                    )
            );

            HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("http://localhost/test.php");
            request.Method = "POST";
            xml.Save( request.GetRequestStream() );
            HttpWebResponse resp = request.GetResponse() as HttpWebResponse;
        }
    }
}
```

and as "receiver":

```
<?php
$fp = fopen('php://input', 'rb');
file_put_contents('test.dat', $fp);
```

afterwards the file test.dat on the server contains

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Foo>
  <bar>
    <type>System.String</type>
    <value>Stackoverflow</value>
  </bar>
  <bar>
    <type>System.Boolean</type>
    <value>True</value>
  </bar>
  <bar>
    <type>System.Char</type>
    <value>x</value>
  </bar>
  <bar>
    <type>System.Int32</type>
    <value>42</value>
  </bar>
</Foo>
```

see also:
[XElement.Save Method (Stream)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc838604.aspx)
[WebRequest.GetRequestStream Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webrequest.getrequeststream.aspx)
http://docs.php.net/wrappers.php.php

Answer (score 0):

I do not know much in C#. but you can send httprequest in c# to the php file and read the response to a varialbe. this can be done from your windows application.

Comment: thanks! I have already got familiar to httprequest, but I need an example, and an explanation for the server side too.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using [SOAP](http://www.w3.org/TR/soap12-part1/), for the reason that it is a well known specification that your colleagues/clients/partners/etc. will be able to understand as well after reading the documentation. Seems like a better choice than coming up with your own specification. Also, there are many others who have used SOAP, so finding examples should be easy.

Here is some info to start with:
[W3C](http://www.w3.org/TR/soap12-part1/), [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SOAP)

Comment: Thanks, but what you are suggeest is changing the whole project... not only my part.

Comment: You'd need to make a SOAP envelop in C# and open it in PHP to get your XML document out. It's a little more work than just sending it the way VolkerK suggests and I can see how this could be a tad overkill for a small project. I'd still suggest it for bigger projects which need to be documented well, though. The little more effort put in to use an existing standard rather than creating one yourself pays itself back many times when writing documentation. :)

Comment: Thanks! maybe I use your advice in future projects.
I'll need to learn that protocol till then.